# Where do I find info on if my Azure VM Reserved instance is properly assigned?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have only one VM and one reserved VM instance. When I bought the reserved instance, it said that I should check the usage log to see which resource it was associated with. I don't see a usage log, but I do see an activity log. (Same?) Either way, it shows nothing about the reserved instance. This Azure UI is not even close to intuitive. How can I see if the reserved instance is properly associated with my VM?

Thanks.

Comment: Did the below solution help?

Comment: I am not sure. My Azure subscription was converted to a Visual Studio Enterprise subscription (from Pay-As-You-Go). After the conversion, my RI is missing. I'm not sure if a VS subscription does not support this feature or what... I have a ticket opened. Once that is cleared up, I will be able to follow up.

Comment: Let me know if there is any update on this. Thanks

Comment: As it turns out, Visual Studio Azure subscriptions do not support reserved instances. It took a little back and forth, but I ended up getting reimbursed for the RI. Now I no longer need an answer to this question, at this time. I'm not sure if the guy that did the conversion knew this would happen, but he didn't say anything, to me. Once we go live and move beyond the VS subscription, and I have RIs, again, I will try out the PS stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to get the information on your reserved instances:

1. [Using the Reserved Instance usage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-reserved-instance-usage)
   This doc describes how to get the Reserved Instance usage summary as well as Reserved Instance usage details.

   GET Method URI:
   https://consumption.azure.com/v2/enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/reservationdetails?startDate={yyyy-mm-dd}&endDate={yyyy-mm-dd}

   GET Method URI: https://consumption.azure.com/v2/enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/reservationsummaries?grain=daily&startdate={yyyy-mm-dd}&enddate={yyyy-mm-dd}
2. For info on scope, type and utilization, you can go to Azure Portal >> Navigate to All Services >> Reservations.